# Excel Macro to Copy & Paste Values from Multiple Sheets to Separate Text Files

Tags: vba, macros

I am trying to build a macro to export multiple sheets (with named tabs) to separate text files. The original .xlsm file has formulas built in, so I am trying to paste the values from each named worksheet into individual text files. The script below works, but only saves the main Excel file as .xlsx and the active worksheet.

I am trying to copy/paste all worksheets, but my script is not working:

```
Sub SaveSheetsAsTxt()
'
' SaveSheetsAsTxt Macro
'
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'save as XLSX
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="V:\tech\dd\FUND_HOLDINGS.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="V:\tech\dd" & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".txt", _
FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Next ws

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Add `ws.activate` as the first line inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with what you have there.

- The Close statement doesn't need to be called inside the loop
- The FileFormat for the .xlsx workbook needed to be changed to work properly when saving from .xlsm to .xlsx. it should be `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`
- As  Scott pointed out, you should activate the worksheet that you are trying to save each time as you iterate.

  ```
  Sub SaveSheetsAsTxt()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  'save as XLSX
  Worksheets.Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="V:\tech\dd\FUND_HOLDINGS.xlsx", _
  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
  ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
  ' Close the newly created xlsx file
  ActiveWorkbook.Close

  'loop through the worksheets
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      ws.Activate
      ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
      ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="V:\tech\dd" & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".txt", _
      FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
  Next ws

  'Close out the workbook now 
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: The reason the the OP is saving before is he/she is saving a copy to which they are doing all the changes.  This is to avoid removing all the formulas from the workbook.  They make a copy, in that copy the remove all the formulas and leave the values, it is this copy which they are iterating and saving as txt files.

Comment: Scott. Sorry, I think I deleted your second comment...I was trying to delete my own.

Comment: No I deleted it, I wanted to double check that my logic was correct.

Comment: oh, yah...I was thinking it was odd that I would be able to.  It just disappeared when I deleted mine so I started to wonder what I did.

Comment: Thank you, everyone for your comments and help!

Scott and ghg565, the macro works great! If someone reads this, I did make one minor change to the following line:

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="V:\tech\dd" & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: I updated this from FileFormate=xlNormal to xlText. (Just an FYI depending on the output you want). 

Thanks again for the help! Very much appreciated! DD

Comment: I am glad you got it working the way you desired.  I have modified the answer to reflect the `xlText` change that you made.